# Pageable and PageRequest Issue

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hey everyone i have been trying to make this tutorial in youtube about spring boot and angular js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBLXWIhrg7U
i have some trouble with using pageRequest Page<> in Java ps this is my controller

```
package cat.Controller;
import cat.dao.ProduitRepository;
import cat.entities.Produit;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProduitController {


@Autowired 
private ProduitRepository produitRepository ;
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
return "test";  
}
@RequestMapping("/save")
public Produit saveProduit(Produit p)
{
    produitRepository.save(p);
    return p ; 
}

@RequestMapping("/all")
public List<Produit> getProduits()
{
    return produitRepository.findAll();

}
@RequestMapping("/produit")
public Page<Produit> getProduits(int page)
{
    return produitRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, 5));

}
**@RequestMapping("/produict")
public Page<Produit> getProduitss(String mc,int page)
{
    return produitRepository.produitmc(mc, new PageRequest(page, 5) );**

}
```

and this my Dao layer using JpaRepository

```
package cat.dao;


import java.awt.print.Pageable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import cat.entities.Produit;



public interface ProduitRepository extends JpaRepository<Produit, Long>  {
// recuperé par mot clé
@Query("select p from produit as p where p.ref like x ")
public Page<Produit> produitmc (@Param("x")Long mc, Pageable p);
public List<Produit> findByRef (Long ref);
public List<Produit> findByRef (Long ref, Pageable p);

}
```

the function produitmc is  suppose to make me search in entity produit by Ref the Erorr is in the function in controller (Bold) and it says

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The method produitmc(Long, Pageable) in the type ProduitRepository is not applicable for the arguments (String, PageRequest)    ProduitController.java  /Mycatalogue/src/main/java/cat/Controller   line 45 Java Problem

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/produict")
     public Page<Produit> getProduitss(String mc,int page)
    {
     return produitRepository.produitmc(mc, new PageRequest(page, 5)    );` is where the eroor shows

Comment: Ofcourse it won't compile. You are accepting a `String` but your method accepts a `Long`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.... Seems your argument passed doesn't match datatype expected. Else it should work.